# odoo v12 xpath new field not visible

Tags: xpath, odoo-12, expr

i have a issue with odoo v12.

manifest file

```
'depends': ['stock','product'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    'views/stock_production_lot_views.xml',
    # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',

],
```

The module class

```
class ProductionLot(models.Model):
 _inherit = '''stock.production.lot'''
 newfield = fields.Char(string='New field', store=False)
```

Right now the form view file

```
<record id="production_lot_form_view" model="ir.actions.act_window">
<field name="name">view.production.lot.form.my</field>
<field name="res_model">stock.production.lot</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_production_lot_form" />
<field name="priority">10</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
  <xpath expr="//group/field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
   <field name="newfield />
  </xpath>
</field>
```

My issue is the module was successfully installed but the field niewfield is not visible into my form.
(if i use model="ir.ui.view" ... name="model", i got an error message, that's why i use model="ir.actions.act_window" ..... name="res_model").
Help please ans thanks .

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/odoo-v12-xpath-not-visible-145057

Comment: Permissions or Grants for the parent _inherit = '''stock.production.lot''' ???? I m a admin profile

Comment: Is your new field loaded to your database? Settings->Technical->models->etc...